# Does the letter "т" in Russian tend to be "ч" in its Ukrainian parallel?

Tags: фонетика, non-native-speaker, чергування, приголосні

I noticed that "**хотя бы**" in Russian becomes "**хоча б**"`. Is it true that in the Ukrainian language letter "ч" sometimes corresponds to the Russian "т" when the words have the same proto-slavic root?" Is this a phenomenon that can be found in other parallel words in Russian and Ukrainian or it is just an exception?

I'm asking it because I learnt a little bit Russian and I study Ukrainian too, and I can find a such rule helping me to identify words more quickly.

Answer (score 9):

First off, a small correction: it has nothing to do with the orthography (I have retagged the question); the sounds alternate, and the written letters only follow the pronunciation.

---

The [Consonant Alternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternation_(linguistics)) is a common phenomenon in Slavonic languages.

Particularly, Ukrainian has [numerous cases](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2) of Alternation.

Namely, `/t/ ←→ /t͡ʃ/` alternation has been caused by [Iotation in Proto-Slavonic language](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) and occurs in verbs having `-ті-`, `-ти-` at the end of the stem (hence the iotation `ti → tji`).

- *to want* — хо**т**іти — хо**ч**у (1SG), хо**ч**е (3SG), хо**ч**уть (3PL);
- *to fly* — ле**т**іти — ле**ч**у (1SG), however ле**т**ить (3SG), ле**т**ять (3PL);
- *to pay* — пла**т**ити — пла**ч**у́ (1SG);
- *to dam up* — га**т**ити — га**ч**у́ (1SG);
- *to spin* — кру**т**ити, вер**т**іти — кру**ч**у, вер**ч**у (1SG);

---

However, the case of *"хоча"* is even more interesting. According to [Vasmer's dictionary](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-15110.htm), *хоча* is a remnant of **Optative**<sup>1</sup> mood of the verb *хотіти*, and the Optative has been usually expressed with the suffixes `iê, iiê` in Proto-Indo-European (PIE) and Proto-Slavonic (PSl) — mind the iotation again.

So, in Ukrainian the form `-tiê` has evolved into `-t͡ʃa`, while in russian it reduced to `-tja`.

Note that the russian retains `-ч-` in this very verb when used in 1st person singular:

- *to want* — хо**т**еть — хо**ч**у (1SG).

---

> find a such rule helping me to identify words more quickly.

This must be the most difficult part. The phonology of Slavonic languages have a lot of sound elisions, alternations, reductions, and epenthesis. There are some formal rules that go as deep as to PIE, and many of them have exceptions, too. The `/t/ ←→ /t͡ʃ/` alternation is just one of them.

This may sound unscientific, :-) but if I were you, I would not depend on deeply-buried formal rules here. Just like an English learner might be marveled with the vowel in *"women"*; Maybe there's a historical reason and a formal rule governing why this word is pronounced this way, but it would be easier to simply remember the word and focus on usage instead.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> [**Optative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optative_mood)  is a grammatical mood that indicates a speaker's wish or hope. Speaking about its modality, it stands between the [Imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) (a very strong wish) and the [Subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) (a soft desire or hope).